# Installation Fail: Steam

Tags: games, steam

Tried to install steam and the terminal keeps throwing up this password confirmation. I type in the password I set and it starts "..............." then ends with"

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Depends: libglapi-mesa:i386 (= 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4)
 unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages."
```

*note* This is the first time I used Linux as an operating system. I'm much more familiar with windows command structure. ~Be gentle.

Answer (score 1):

open a terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge libglapi-mesa:i386 libcheese-gtk23 libcheese7
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install libglapi-mesa:i386 libcheese-gtk23 libcheese7
sudo apt-get install steam
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answer should work, although I personally ran into some problems when attempting it. What worked for me was running the install from the terminal, rather than downloading the .deb from steampowered.com. All I did was run `sudo apt-get install steam -y` to get it installed. It loaded the EULA in the terminal, press tab a couple of times to select ok, then watch it load. Once installed, it should start automatically, update everything, and work. Hope this helps, just in case the above answer doesn't.